# Excel Conditionally SUM rows totals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel like this:

[image]

I want to sum the totals by when (month), type and if it's in the budget. For example I want a result like this:

[image]

So... it "search" for every when with the same month, multiply the ammount but "in budget" column, and in sums everything by type that matches that.

I hope I explained well!! I think the result image will help!

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prepared to generate another column (here: F) into your workbook like

```
    A    B    C     D     E    F
1   when curr type  amnt  budg 
2   2    U    F      85   1    F21
3   2    U    T      50   1    T21
4   2    U    T     150   1    T21
5   2    U    T     380   1    T21
6   3    U    G     600   1    G31
7   3    Y    G     250   1    G31
8   6    U    T     600   1    T61
9   9    U    T     500   0    T90

[F2] = C2 & A2 & E2 
[F3] = C3 & A3 & E3
...
```

Then you can do the sums with:

```
[A12] = sumif($F$2:$F$9, "F21", $A$2:$A$9)   ' for when=2, type="F" and "in budget"
[A13] = sumif($F$2:$F$9, "T21", $A$2:$A$9)   ' for when=2, type="T" and "in budget"
...
```